# Regexp works with sublime text search but not from python script

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext2

I want to search  a file's contents using regular expressions. A sample of the file is:

```
3 General 24
3.1 CR IOT133 (ID: 194) 24
3.1.1 Issue 24
4 Integration 25
4.11 CR IOT025 (ID: 125) 25
10.27 CR IOT111 (ID: 176) 77
```

And I want to extract the IOTxxx part (so lines 2, 5 and 6 in this example)

My script is:

```
import re
fhandle = open("CR_headers.txt")
inp = fhandle.read()
crnumlist = re.findall('^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2} CR (IOT\d{3}).*$', inp)
print crnumlist
```

The last statement prints an empty list. I tried running it from the console as well but the result is the same.

If I use sublime text find with input: `^\d{1}\.\d{1} CR (IOT\d{3}).*$`
I can get the matching lines.

Using python version 2.7.10 and sublime text 2 on a windows 7 box

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong will be greatly appreciated. Thanx

Comment: if i use crnumlist = re.findall('\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2} CR (IOT\d{3})', inp) it works but still I would like to understand what was wrong with the first one.

Comment: Is `regex` necessary here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to include multi line modifier and define your regex as raw string. You must use the multi-line modifier when these two conditions are met.

- Whenever anchors `^`, `$` are used in your input regex.
- And when the input string contain more than one line.

  ```
  crnumlist = re.findall(r'(?m)^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2} CR (IOT\d{3}).*$', inp)
  ```

Example:

```
>>> s = '''3 General 24
3.1 CR IOT133 (ID: 194) 24
3.1.1 Issue 24
4 Integration 25
4.11 CR IOT025 (ID: 125) 25
10.27 CR IOT111 (ID: 176) 77'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2} CR (IOT\d{3}).*$', s)
['IOT133', 'IOT025', 'IOT111']
>>> re.findall(r'^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2} CR (IOT\d{3}).*$', s)
[]
```